# In MVC DateTime? not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC 4 application. In the UI, I have a field that uses a time picker to pick Start and End Time in the format of `HH:mm`. But at the moment I select a value 07:00 validation message says `The field Start Time must be a date.` I am using jQuery validation plugin:

```
class booking
{
DateTime? StartTime{get;set;}
}
```

**View**

```
 @model booking
 StartTime:  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartTime, "TimePicker")
```

**Shared/EditorTemplates/TimePicker.cshtml**

```
@model DateTime?
@{
String modelValue = "";
var dateFormat = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;

if (Model.HasValue)
{
    if (Model.Value != DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        modelValue = Model.Value.ToString("HH:mm", dateFormat);
    }
}
}
@Html.TextBox("", modelValue)
```

***HTML Rendered***

```
 <input type="text" value="" name="StartTime" id="StartTime" 
 data-val-date="The field Start time must be a date." data-val="true" 
 class="hasTimepicker input-validation-error" />
```

What is the problem? why mvc fires validation with this editor template?
it was working in mvc 3. why not in mvc4?

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: The error message you're getting is not displayed by MVC but by jQuery.

Comment: Why would you specify that it must be a *date* when it's actually meant to be a *time*?

Comment: @JonSkeet, i would like to capture timing like `07:00` or `23:00` hours. I think its a date type i should use. Does c# has a datatype for this? or do i use string?

Comment: @JonSkeet, there is no `Date` and no `Time` datatype in c#, but `DataTime`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of binding to a DateTime, bind to a TimeSpan. DateTime cannot exist without a date component.

Comment: @Billa Sure, will do when I get home.

Comment: Think he lives pretty far